# Check row uniqueness on INSERT with nullable alternate (exactly one of many) foreign keys

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I'm working with EF Code First (Core) and have a roles table which looks like this:

```
Id PK
Object1Id FK 
Object2Id FK
RoleId FK NOT NULL
UserId FK
UserGroupId FK
```

Depending on who has the role, either UserId or UserGroupId must be filled.
Depending on the fact to which type of object this role related, either Object1Id or Object2Id must be filled.

Now I want to prevent that duplicate data be inserted into this table, but "unique row" is defined like this: "the following combinations are unique: [Object1Id, RoleId, UserId], [Object1Id, RoleId, UserGroupId], [Object2Id, RoleId, UserId], [Object2Id, RoleId, UserGroupId]".

I tried to add the following to StorageContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().HasAlternateKey(c => new { c.RoleId, c.Object1Id, c.UserId });
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().HasAlternateKey(c => new { c.RoleId, c.Object2Id, c.UserId });
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().HasAlternateKey(c => new { c.RoleId, c.Object1Id, c.UserGroupId });
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().HasAlternateKey(c => new { c.RoleId, c.Object2Id, c.UserGroupId });
```

However the migration didn't work because alternate keys cannot contain nullable fields.

Is there an EF solution for this? 
A pure SQL solution would also be fine. But what is a good one? I was thinking about INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger, where I would select a value and insert only in the case if it does not exist, but I'm not a DB expert and I'm not sure if this is an appropriate solution.

Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**
As nicely hinted in the comments, it's unique index that I wanted:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().HasIndex(c => new { c.RoleId, c.Object1Id, c.UserId }).IsUnique();
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().HasIndex(c => new { c.RoleId, c.Object2Id, c.UserId }).IsUnique();
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().HasIndex(c => new { c.RoleId, c.Object1Id, c.UserGroupId }).IsUnique();
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().HasIndex(c => new { c.RoleId, c.Object2Id, c.UserGroupId }).IsUnique();
```

I hope only this won't "kill" the performance.

Comment: Unique indexes?

Comment: True.. Sometimes you have to ask it just to understand it. Thanks for the hint.